# MongoDB query - find one of each from tag array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to do a "where $in" query in MongoDB/Mongoose where I only want one result back for each tag in an array. Sort of like:

```
db.images.find( { hashtag : { $in : ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'] } } );
```

And I would get three unique results back; each from the set of tags I specified.

```
[{name:'image1', hashtag:'tag1'},
{name:'image55', hashtag:'tag2'},
{name:'image99', hashtag:'tag3'}]
```

In SQL you'd use something like GROUP BY, but I can't find the equivalent in MongoDB without doing a Map/Reduce.

Anyway of doing that? Thanks.

--edit
The equivalent SQL for what I want would be:

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE hashtag in ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3') GROUP BY hashtag;
```

Or ideally, though MongoDB has no random

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE hashtag in ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3') GROUP BY hashtag ORDER BY rand();
```

Comment: Could you clarify what your document looks like?  Is it name and hashtag array?  I don't actually see what SQL group by would do for you here - it looks like you want any single image name with tag1, any one with tag2 and any with tag3?  I'm not even sure this is easily solvable in your application, let alone within a query...

Comment: No, my docs don't actually look like that. This is just an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: The SQL would be pretty easy for this: SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `hashtag` in ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3') GROUP BY `hashtag`;

Comment: relational wouldn't have an array of hashtags so I still don't understand your SQL example.  Is your assumption that SQL would have a row for each name/hashtag pair? That will be available in 2.2 with aggregation framework where you can unwind arrays, but you will still have to solve the problem of how to guarantee you have every name and every hashtag without repeats.

Comment: I didn't say "hashtag" was an array. It's being used as a string field in this example.

Comment: sorry, I was misled into thinking arrays because the other answer mentioned $unwind which is how you can turn a document with an array of tags into multiple documents, each with one tag.  See my answer below then.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are waiting for the 2.2 release of MongoDB which will include an aggregation pipeline that will allow you to unwind arrays into multiple results.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation

Comment: I think you meant to link http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework though I'm not sure it will help in this exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to do this in 2.0 but in 2.2 (currently available as development version 2.1.1 - only available for testing but **not** production) the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/) will allow you to do it like this (just as an example, I'm sure other ways are possible):

```
  db.images.aggregate( 
       {$match   : {hashtag: {$in:["tag1","tag2"]}}}, 
       {$group   : {_id:"$hashtag", name: {$first:"$name"}}},
       {$project : {hashtag:"$_id", name: "$name", _id:0}}
  )
```

Which returns:

```
{
         "result" : [
        {
            "hashtag" : "tag2",
            "name" : "1"
        },
        {
            "hashtag" : "tag1",
            "name" : "1"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
  }
```

This is assuming your documents are of the form {name:"xxx",hashtag:"tagX") and many names correspond to each hashtag.  What the aggregation pipeline is doing is it's using $match to limit the working set to ones that have hashtag as "tag1" or "tag2", then we group by hashtag and specify we only want to keep $first result of each grouping ($last is another option) - this assumes you don't care which of the names you get back as long as it's just one.  $project is used to map _id which group requires back to field name "hashtag".